# Codenameone : Alternative to webBrowsers

Tags: codenameone

I m wandering if there is an alternative to webBrowsers in codenameOne. I tried using webBrowser but there is an issue with tabs : github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1711

I need to enrich my textAreas which are filled dynamically
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [issue](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1711) was just fixed and even when it existed it was only triggered when the tabs were at the side and not when they were on top/bottom.

FYI updates are released every Friday so by next week this should work.

As to your question you can construct a UI dynamically e.g. [check this out](https://github.com/shannah/cn1-xmlview).